# How to access the "app" folder via browser (localhost) in cakePHP?

Tags: apache, cakephp, php

I am using Apache server. Usually when I want to start a new website project, I created a new folder inside my server directory and inside that folder I would have 'index.html or index.php'. When I direct my localhost URL to that folder, it would open it and automatically display index.php.

Now I am trying something new with this CakePHP framework. I finished setting it up, and when I direct my localhost URL to folder 'cakephp-cakephp' (folder containing all the cakePHP files), it then shows me this message:

```
Release Notes for CakePHP 2.0.0-dev.

Your tmp directory is writable.

The FileEngine is being used for caching. To change the config edit APP/config/core.php

Your database configuration file is present.
```

I think the next step here is to start the development by saving all my files to "app" folder. But the message is not gone even when I deleted the default index.php files from inside the folder 'cakephp-cakephp'. It seems anyway, the index.php files do not actually generate the message.

Does anybody know what file generates that release notes message? I want to delete that file so that I wont get the message (which I believe is triggered by some default file like 'index.php') when I access folder 'cakephp-cakephp', and then it will show me the file directory inside that folder instead, and I can traverse file directory easily using my browser and access my app folder, in which I am planning to store my index.php file, and save all my development files..

Comment: I don't know cake at all but if you're on a unix machine grep is a wonderful tool. navigate to your root cake folder in the terminal and type in... grep -r "paste text to search for in here" . <--the preceding dot is part of the command

Comment: This might not be helpful, but its pretty obvious you have not gone through any of the tutorials (or spent any time in the manual) on the CakePHP site. All of what you are saying is clearly answered in the there. And if you are serious about learning to use the Cake framework, you should really start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete the index.php files and you usually don't modify those files unless you need to do some special configuration. Adding the file app/views/pages/home.ctp gets rid of that message and becomes your default home page.

Also, as stated in the comments, you should really read the manual and try the tutorial.
http://book.cakephp.org

Comment: +1 for the link.
@BennyTjia : read it a bit, then try to be Wild Wild West with any framework.

Comment: @Everyone:I spent a few moments reading some of the tutorials yesterday and I think I have managed to find my way around this framework. I am new to this MVC thing, i hope i can get used to it